# If input box contains certain number of characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="text"/> <button>Go</button>

<div id="example">
</div>
```

How can I `.append` "Blah" in `#example` if `input` contains 5 characters when `button` is clicked, and `.append` "Other" if it doesn't?

Comment: what is the code that you have used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var example = $('#example');    //get example div
var input = $('input').get(0);  //get first input in the set of inputs

$('button').click(function(){   //bind click handlers to (any) button
   var value = input.value;     //get the (first) input's value
   if(value.length === 5){      //check the value
      example.append('Blah');
   } else {
      example.append('Other');
   }
});
```

Comment: Please append $ to variables declared by you for DOM elements. It will be easy to differentiated with other variables.

Comment: @Murtaza actually, i don't advise that. (Almost) Anything in JS is an object, regardless if they're from the DOM or not. therefore, they should be treated the same.

Comment: But it helps in identifying the variables with Elements, good practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var $example = $('#example');
    if ($('input').val().length == 5) {
        $example.append('Blah');
    } else {
        $example.append('Other');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/cks45/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){        
    if($('input').val().length == 5){
      $('#example').append('blah');
    }else{
      $('#example').append('Other');
    }
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS way

```
var butt = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0],
    input =  document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0],
    example = document.getElementById("example");

butt.onclick = function(){
    if(input.value.length == 5){
        example.textContent += "blah";
    }else{
        example.textContent += "other";
    }
}
```

​

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pLZRV/2/)**
​

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').on('click',function() { 
    $('#example').text(
        $('#example').text() +
        ($('input[type=text]').val().length==5?'Blah':'Other')
    );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want to use jquery you could do...

HTML

```
<input id="input1" type="text"/> <button onclick="go('input1')">Go</button>

<div id="example">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function go(inputId){
    document.getElementById("example").innerHTML += document.getElementById(inputId).value.length === 5 ? "bla" : "other";
}
```

This involved changing the HTML to include an id for the input and an onclick event handler for the button.